# How to return a message and redirect users in Django middleware

Tags: django, geolocation, middleware, django-middleware

In my Django application, I pull a user's IP address and set a local city. However, if a user is out of the geographical area that the app covers, I want to raise an error and redirect them to the geographical area that this app covers. I'm trying to do this with middleware, but not sure how to do this.

```
class RestrictUserMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')

        if x_forwarded_for:
            ipaddress = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[-1].strip()
        else:
           ipaddress = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

        ip = get_client_ip(request)
        reader = geoip2.database.Reader(path)
        try: 
            location = reader.city(ip)
        except:
            location = True

        if not response.subdivisions.most_specific.iso_code in 'CA':
            # raise error message here that it's not available outside CA
            request.session['city'] = 'Beverly Hills'
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
...
'package name.python file name.RestrictUserMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: Sorry didn't share my settings - I have this already. My question is related how to return both an error message and redirect the user in the middleware